# T-SQL - get banded results from two columns in tabular format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Imagine a data set like this:

```
create table #temp (id int, value_band nvarchar(99), date-band nvarchar(99))

ID     Value_Band    Date_Band
1234   0-5           0-12
3466   0-5           13-24 
4682   5-15          13-24
3468   15-25         24-36
3457   5-15          36+
3579   25+           0-12
```

.. and so on: I've about about 80,000 of these records.

It's easy enough to use `GROUP BY` to get total counts for each band. However, I've been asked to break the total counts of each type down into a grid, like this:

```
               Value_Band
Date_Band    0-5    5-15    15-25    25+
0-12
13-24
24-36
36+
```

So if there are, say 4,000 records with a Date_Band of 0-12 and there just happens to be a thousand of each possible value_band, the top row would have 1,000 in each column.

While I can do this piecemeal - work out what goes in each box - I'm curious to know if there's a single statement that will produce this results set.

I'm sure this is a common question/requirement and the answer is straightforward enough. But existing answers I've seen are reliant on one of the grid axis to exist as separate columns, which is not the case with this data.

Comment: Did you tried [`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Comment: I've looked at PIVOT, and while it's clear I'm going to need it, I'm struggling to understand how I can use it to do what's required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) rotates a table-valued expression by turning the unique values from one column in the expression into multiple columns in the output, and performs aggregations where they are required on any remaining column values that are wanted in the final output.*

This is what you need.

```
SELECT
  date_band,
  [0-5],
  [5-15],
  [15-25],
  [25+]
FROM (
  -- Subquery to retrieve the required columns
  SELECT
    id, value_band, date_band
  FROM
    temp
) T
PIVOT (
  -- Aggregation
  COUNT(id)
  -- The column to rotate and the list of values you want to show (listed as columns)
  FOR value_band IN ([0-5], [5-15], [15-25], [25+])
) P
```

Here is another solution without `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT
  date_band,
  SUM(CASE WHEN value_band = '0-5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [0-5],
  SUM(CASE WHEN value_band = '5-15' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [5-15],
  SUM(CASE WHEN value_band = '15-25' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [15-25],
  SUM(CASE WHEN value_band = '25+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [25+]
FROM
  temp
GROUP BY
  date_band
```

Please note, that in each cases, you have to know the values you want to rotate.

And an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96eef6/4) demo

Comment: Thanks for the helpful explanation, and an alternative using a technique I understand so I can see how it translates. Excellent answer.